# System too lean at low fuel level

Tags: fuel-system, nissan, rpm

My car shows lean condition at low fuel level. Also it exhibits low fuel average and low rpm and loaa of power.  I have Nissan dayz 660 cc with 64000 on ODO.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  The car shows check engine light when fuel tank is about to 25 pc. RPM also drops at idle position

Comment: Okay, I think you said most of that in the body of your question, but I'm still not getting exactly what you want answered. Have you checked the fuel pressure to ensure it's good? What is considered a "low fuel level"? What does "low fuel average" mean to you? What is low rpm considered? Low on power as compared to what? If you can help us out here with a BUNCH more details and a true question (what exactly are you trying to solve), we might be able to help. Please edit your question and throw as much information into it as you can, please.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks for ur concern regarding to my question. By low fuel level I mean fuel level in tank. When the fuel tank level is about 30 percent check engine light comes on and on checking with obd scanner it shows system too leam p0171.

Comment: Low fuel average means that car consumes more fuel than it is suppose to do. And rpm are also not stable. It shows shaky behaviour when shiftung transmission

Comment: The car runs perfectly fine when above the 30% level? Also, if you filled up your car from the 30% (where car behaves erratically) to see how much fuel it takes, then compared it to how much should take to fill it up? Also wondering if there might be a leak (sucking fumes) in the fuel pump pickup inside the tank.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Car behaviour doesn't changes much avove 30 percent. However situation becomes worser below 30 percent.